# Adding tags to bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty

For a while now, most bounties on our site are rewards for existing answers. As a consequence, it's pretty hard to spot any bounty that would fall into the 'Draw attention' or 'Bonus / Side challenge' categories -- and we have to open each and every entry to figure it out. I've to admit that I personally don't really pay attention to the bounty list anymore because of that.

Ideally, I think SE should display the bounty reason on the bounty list. But since they don't, should we include this information by ourselves?

We may either:

- Add temporary tags such as `bounty-side-challenge` or `bounty-reward` to the challenge. But I don't really like the idea of creating new tags for this specific purpose.
- Temporarily edit the title of the challenge to include the bounty reason, e.g. `Some great challenge [REWARD]` or `[REWARD] Some great challenge`.

Either way, this would be some extra work for either the bounty owner (assuming that they're aware of this new custom) and/or the moderators if the owner is not doing it the right way.

Comment: How common are 'Draw attention' and 'Bonus / Side challenge' bounties?

Answer (score 5):

*Full disclosure: I'm very much at fault for this situation.*

I don't think a manual process can work.

However, it should be possible to add entries to [the bounty filter box](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Bounties)'s **Filter by** column for each of the possible bounty reasons:
[image: current bounty filter box]

Then you could de-select "Reward existing answer":
[image: proposed bounty filter box]

However, this would need to be a general SE feature, so I suggest you take it up on mother Meta.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355303/317948).

Comment: It's possible a userscript might work for this. I'm loathe to suggest people need to have multiple different browser extensions in order to enjoyable browse the site, but if Mother Meta is opposed to it, a userscript might be the next best option

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I'm not sure how a userscript can detect type without fetching each page.

Comment: @Adám It might be possible with SE API, and then caching the results. A userscript isn't the best solution, but it isn't too difficult to write or install them

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, use temporary tags for this

I like the idea of marking bountied challenges with temporary tags indicating the purpose of the bounty. I don't see a problem in creating a few tags for that.

If the owner is not aware of the custom, any other user with enough reputation can add the tag (as is often done in regular challenges). If everyone forgets to add the tag in some bountied challenge, it's true that the challenge loses visibility, especially when we all get used to seeing bountied challenges by tags.

There's also the question that the tag needs to be removed when the bounty expires. And *that* is easier to forget than adding the tag. But I don't see this as an important issue, because the challenge will not show up in the "bountied" tab anymore, so it won't cause clutter.

Another minor thing is that the challenge may already have five tags. In that case one of them would have to be temporarily removed, to be added back later. Again, no big deal.

All in all, I think the advantages outweigh the drawbacks.

Comment: One potential thing to keep in mind is if multiple challenges are tagged/untagged in quick succession, it may clutter up the front page, so, if this happens, tagging should be done as normal, leaving some time between posts if a lot of posts are being tagged at the same time

Comment: Starting a bounty already bumps the challenge, so I don't see any problem of tag-editing already bumped post. I could even say that the tag edit should be done as soon as one puts a bounty on it.